# Transform log file using awk

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a Java log file and want to transform it using `awk`. The file has following record structure:

```
filename:date time [level] (thread) message
```

Here is an example line:

```
2018-01-19-19.prod.com.gz:2018-01-19 19:14:29,964 [INFO] (Runner for {AccountId: ‘1234’, JobFlowId: ‘abcd’, TaskId: ‘4321’, Type: ‘TestType’}) com.damluar.AbstractObjectCache: Found unexpired object in local cache for key: testkey
```

The resulting file needs to have fields and have \t as separators:

- data + time **(sorted)**
- level
- thread
- message

If I use whitespace or `:` as separator then content of `thread` and `message` fields got split too. What would be the best way to process it?

Comment: you should at least give some lines of your log as example, what do you think?

Comment: Will the thread field contain (nested (parentheses))?

Comment: I posted an example. No, thread is not expected to have nested parens.

Comment: post the fragment of resulting file in formatted manner. What field separator should be in resulting file?

Comment: tabs should be a separator, so that I can treat it as csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/:/:\t/;s/\[/\t&/;s/\]/&\t/;s/)/)\t/' log
```

the above line will separate the required fields by `tab`. If you want to output them, you can pipe it to awk to check:

```
echo "yourExample"||sed 's/:/:\t/;s/\[/\t&/;s/\]/&\t/;s/)/)\t/'|awk -F '\t' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)print $i}'
2018-01-19-19.prod.com.gz:
2018-01-19 19:14:29,964 
[INFO]
 (Runner for {AccountId: ‘1234’, JobFlowId: ‘abcd’, TaskId: ‘4321’, Type: ‘TestType’})
 com.damluar.AbstractObjectCache: Found unexpired object in local cache for key: testkey
```